# There is an op amp in switching power supply

Tags: amplifier, switch-mode-power-supply

[image: Switching Power Supply]

I still can't figure out what is function of the operational amplifier?

Answer (score 6):

It is an **error amplifier**. The amplifier provides an analog feedback signal through the LED/phototransistor to control the PWM across the isolation barrier.

Here is what a real circuit typically looks like (schematic from [this](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/archive/2014/01/16/powerlab-notes-how-to-regulate-a-low-voltage-isolated-supply) TI document):

[image]

Since the circuit is powered by the isolated voltage, the LED is initially 'off' and the PWM runs at maximum output. As the voltage approaches the target voltage the LED current increases, causing the PWM to back off and (if tuned correctly) keeps the voltage from overshooting the target, whilst minimizing the rise time. I agree that your block diagram appears to be reversed from what is normally possible.

The three-pin TL431 contains both an op-amp-like amplifier and a fairly accurate and stable band-gap reference, all for a penny or two!

Answer (score 3):

It is "supposed" to be a voltage comparator. The resistor divider on the right should scale the output voltage to the reference voltage on the op amp '+' input. However, the way the circuit is drawn, the bottom resistor is short-circuited.

The node pointed out by the red arrow (in the following image) is incorrect, it should not be there. The top resistor should not connect to the negative of the DC output, only the positive.

[image]

Comment: Haven't  actually noticed that short at first, good catch

Comment: Why is it just take the real outpout without the resistors into "-"  instead of that voltage divider?

Comment: @user251691 So that the voltage reference in the '+' does not need to be the same of what's expected in the output. It can be a scaled version of it. Say you want 15V at output and your voltage reference is of 5V - the voltage divider would scale the 15V down by a factor of 3, so that the comparation is meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's there to compare the voltage gotten on the output against a reference voltage (shown in the schematic as a battery for some reason) and provide feedback to the control circuit.

This lets one set the output voltage with the resistor divider while using a commonly available voltage reference, such as the TL431, commonly used in this application.

This lets the switcher controller know how should it tweak the PWM's duty cycle, whether to increase it (output voltage too low) or decrease it (output voltage too high).

Take the it just a conceptual schematic to give you a flavour of something rather than applying it directly to a design - I can't actually remember seeing an actual opamp on the secondary side for this purpose, on the stuff I've torn apart. Only some kind of a funny arrangement with an LED being driven through the reference. It works.

The comparator however looks 'backwards' to me, by its two inputs being swapped. I think so because this way the controllers sees the opto as off at first - there shouldn't be any power at the secondary. But once the power goes up, the reference kicks in, being suddenly greater than the sensed voltage, and the opto would turn on. Weird.  Had the inputs been swapped, then it would all make more sense, I think.

Comment: But then how it supposed to be like?

Comment: @RichardTheSpacecat I don't think anything could really be said about whether '+' and '-' connections are flipped without knowing what's inside the black box called "PWM Control Circuit". Maybe it considers a signal on the optocoupler to be "output lower than reference", or the opposite.

Comment: @VicenteCunha Fair enough, it just seems odd to me that it assumes the secondary to have enough power to drive the LED from square one, while somehow maintaining isolation. Or it doesn't, and indeed the black box does all the magic. Who knows.

Comment: It is lowering the condution, (brightness) of the led as the voltage rises, helping control the regulation of the V out

Comment: @SaraHeart The thing I find weird is that the initial condition would be that, assuming there would be no power on the isolated secondary side, there LED would be completely dark, practically indicating a gross overvoltage of the output to the controller. Which isn't right, is it?

Comment: Yes it looks mis-wired

Comment: You are assuming that a LACK of voltage is what causes the feedback to lower the voltage. But the op amp is an inverting amp, meaning that the output will be dropped as the voltage exceeds it's setpoint. So you are not quite understanding how the regulation works.